# Qual método utilizar e como? onLoadResourse ou webResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest

Tags: webview

Estou implementando este projeto [WebApp](https://github.com/marcosnunes/Panomaps).
O que ocorre é que o link da página do Facebook dos anunciantes e os botões de curtir e compartilhar no Twitter não estão funcionando bem como o botão de fazer upload de imagens na página de Publicação de Novo Anunciante.
Pesquisando eu vi que os métodos onLoadResourse e webResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest podem ser a resposta que procuro, porém não tenho conseguido implementá-los.

Alguém pode me ajudar?